# Chrome extension: getBackgroundPage() fails only occasionally

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Chrome extension and the following code causes an error only sometimes, not always. Most of the times, this extension does work properly, but sometimes it fails to getBackgroundPage() and falls into the "else" section.

In popup.js

```
  var bg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
  if (bg) {
    bg.some_function();
  } else {
    this.updateStatus("Browser error. But you don't have to reload the page to fix it. Just switch to any other browser tab and return to fix.");
  }
```

The background page is handled by eventPage.js

manifest.json

```
"background": {
  "scripts": ["eventPage.js","jquery-2.1.1.min.js"],
  "persistent": false
},
```

This extension works as a helper tool of CMS, and provide advanced "search & replace" features. It tends to fail when a user edit a lot of texts in the form on the page. And it can be solved either by reloading the page or switching to any other tab then returning to the tab.

What is the occasion when popup.js fails to getBackgroundPage() ?
and is there any workaround to avoid the issue?

Thanks a lot for your insight!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably using an [Event Page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages), i.e. `"persistent" : false` in the manifest. If left idle, it is unloaded by Chrome.

It is [specifically stated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages#transition) in the docs that `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()` can fail in this case, since it's a synchronous method and if the event page is unloaded there's nothing to return immediately.

To work around it, you should use `chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(callback)` instead. It is asynchronous and is able to wait until the background page is "spun up" for the request.

In general, consider `chrome.extension` API largely (but not fully) deprecated in favor of general `runtime` API.

Comment: Note: read the Event Page docs _very carefully_. They are in general tricky to work with.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response and a precise advice! I will change my implementation according to your advice.

Comment: @user21280 You're welcome! Since you're new to SO: don't forget to mark an answer as "accepted" if it helped you resolve the problem.